# hello, i'm having trouble with this particular image as it is an image that has a multicolor vector

Tags: adobe-illustrator

i'm having trouble with this particular image as it is an image that has a multicolor vector and i need to change it into an ai editable artwork, tried using image trace before but the smaller parts disappears after the application.....would anyone please help me on this? [image]

Comment: Tracing would be the *worst* method to create that. Resetting the type and recreating the little red corners would be a much more efficient method.

Answer (score 1):

Tracing this image might not be the best solution. Complexity of the elements, size, resolution, not so good quality and all other factors might be the reasons for poor results.
I'd recommend the service that helps you to find out about what fonts are used in the image https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/.
Onnce you know what fonts are used, it would be simple to create the vectors.

You might need to split image in few parts/files and test them separately, because the service can only extract the certain amount information by singe test.
Please let us know if you have been succesful.